# Is the set of vectors a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the set of vectors {$v_1, v_2, v_3$} where  $v_1$ = {1, 1, 1}, $v_2$ = {1, -1, 1}, and $v_3$ = {3, 1, 3}, determine if the set is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**What I tried:**

I made the augmented matrix of the three vectors and set it equal to zero to try and prove linear independence. After row reducing to echelon form, I arrived at the system of equations:

$x_1 + 2x_3 = 0$

$x_2 + x_3 = 0$

$x_3$ is free.

Next, I believe that I must show that $x_1, x_2, x_3 = 0$ is the only solution to the system, however, I am not sure if this is true!

I am not sure how to approach from here, however, I know that if the set is linearly independent, then it will prove that the set is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Note $2v_{1}+v_{2} = v_{3}$, so these vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: and therefore it is not a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Correct?

Comment: If a set is linearly dependent it cannot be a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you've reached this point, then all you need to do is:

1. Since $x_3$ is free, choose any valid non-zero value for it.
2. Show that, as a result, you can find a valid non-zero value for either $x_1$ or $x_2$ (or both) that satisfies the system.
3. Hence, the vectors are linearly dependent.

In fact, since in doing the row reduction you show that the matrix $[x_1 x_2 x_3]^T$ does not have full rank, that's actually sufficient to prove linear dependence (you may not have reached an appropriate lemma to prove that, but it's just a simplification of the process I described above).